# Sorting in list

Tags: python, lista

tengo esta lista que dentro de ella hay más listas:

```
list = [[8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 18, 4, 6, 10, 12],
        [21, 22, 25, 26, 27, 20, 24],
        [34, 28, 32, 33, 30, ],
        [38, 39, 42, 44, 35, 36, 40],
        [52, 54, 45, 48, 49, 50, 51, 46]]
```

Este es mi codigo, trato de no usar sort:

```
def ordenar(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        h = i
        while h > 0 and list[h] < list[h - 1]:
            aux = list[h]
            list[h] = list[h - 1]
            list[h - 1] = aux
            h = h - 1
    print("*****", list)
```

Esto es lo que me debe salir pero no me sale nada :

```
[4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18] 
[20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27]
[28, 30, 32, 33, 34]
[35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44] 
[45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que comparas una lista con otra lista. Mira el caso cuando `h = 1`

Cuando haces `list[h]` lo que te devuelve es esta lista `[21, 22, 25, 26, 27, 20, 24]`. Luego haces `list[h-1]` que te devuelve `[8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 18, 4, 6, 10, 12]`

Entonces estarías comparando esto:

```
[21, 22, 25, 26, 27, 20, 24] < [8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 18, 4, 6, 10, 12]
```

*Python te lo permite, pero no es lo que buscas.*

Ahora bien vos deberías acceder a cada sublista de tu lista y ordenarlas como si fuese una lista normal. Si te preguntas como podrías acceder a cada sublista, vuelve a leer desde el principio de este mensaje, está explicito.

Por ultimo, estas usando el nombre de un tipo `list`, te recomiendaría que lo cambies por otro nombre.